# Huge SETTING file to a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, file, dictionary, settings

I have a large .SET file, which  gives the boundary and solver settings from a third party software. The file changes its size and position of parameter according to the settings given while simulation. It has 100's of parameters in it.

A typical setting file looks like this:

```
(rp (
(wall-film/model-parameters ((solve-wallfilm? . #t) (solve-momentum? . #f) 
(solve-energy? . #t) (solve-scalar? . #f) (solve-vapor? . 2) (dpm-
collection? . #f) (mom-gravity? . #t) (mom-aero-drive? . #t) (mom-wall-visc? 
. #t) (mom-pressure? . #f) (mom-spreading? . #f) (ewf-adaptive? . #f) (time-
scheme . 0) (mass-scheme . 0) (mom-scheme . 0) (energy-scheme . 0) (scalar-
scheme . 0) (reconstruct-limiter . 0) (thickness-limit . 1e-05) (thickness-
realistic . 0.) (courant-number . 0.2) (adapt-init-dt . 0.0001) (timestep-
max . 0.01) (sub-time-steps . 10) (sub-iter-nums . 10))
```

I would like to create a function that reads the file and creates a dictionary like the one below for all parameters:

```
 A = {'solve-wallfilm':'t','solve momentum':'t','solve-energy':'t'}
```

Which will help me in future to compare two different setting files.

Could someone suggest me how could I do it in python or what library should I use to put the setting file in a orderly format ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just open the file, read it and split by open bracket, then append the dictionary by splitting each by a point and making dict[split[0]] = split[1][:-1]

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
def settingtodict(filepath):
    d = {}
    with open(filepath,'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            a = line.split("(")
            for each in a:
                print(each)
                if '.' in each:
                    d[each.split('.')[0]]=each.split('.')[1][1:-2]
    return d
```

works as long as everything is on one line

Comment: The problem I have is that, the format of the setting file changes as it goes example and I also want them in the dictionary : (species/pseudo-cycle-type (3 3))
(species/pseudo-time-scale-factor (1. 1.))
(species/pseudo-implicit-relax (1. 1.))
(species/pseudo-specific? (#f #f))
(species/pseudo-relax (0.75 0.75))
(dpm/sources-every-flow-iteration? #t)
(dpm/unsteady-tracking? #t)
(amg/conservative-amg-coarsening? #t)
(pdf/dynamic-fvar? #f)
(omega/relax 0.699999988079071)
(k/relax 0.699999988079071)
(turb-viscosity/relax 0.8999999761581421)

Comment: Well then you'll be best using that but with loads of if char in each: lines to change how it adds dependent upon the content currently being dealt with

Comment: Thats a very complex settings file. You'll just have to look through isolating each different kind of entry and setting up logic to deal with it